# Java webapp API id-based security filter

Tags: filter, jax-rs, security-roles, access-rules

We're building our API and looking for an organized way to grant users access based on what role and permission they have.

From the starting point, we have 3 roles

- Admin: can get and edit everything in his organization
- Team Admin: can get and edit only his team info and users' info
- User: can get any edit his own information

Entity

- Team
- User

For Security Filters:

1. We're using JAX-RS with Security Roles and @RoleAllowed to filter access to resources
2. Id-based filter by if / then / else function. Example with a team admin access to a user.

   ```
   function isAllowAccess(teamAdminId, userId) {
       allowedUserIdsList = queryfor(teamAdminId);
       if (userId in allowedUserIdsList) then ... else BAD_REQUEST 
   }
   ```

This code is growing with the increase complexity of multiple roles and many entities. So my questions:

1. What will be the best way to have an organized id-based filter, is there reputable library for this?
2. Should we maintain a separate table containing accessible ids of each
   entity for each team_admin_id? Then every row updated or inserted will trigger the update of this table.
3. Is there a formal or widely acceptable method to reduce database
   call overhead in each call just to check if the team_admin is
   allowed to access a particular user?